# Adding a new disk drive to a Synology 2-bay drive

Tags: nas

I've got a Synology 2-bay NAS (DS213). Initially I added a single 3 TB disk. It was configured with SHR (with no data protection). I have some data in it too.

Now I've got a new disk, and have added it into the 2nd bay.

Is it possible to add this new drive into the same Volume?

My goal is to ensure that data protection can be enabled.

When I open the DSM Storage Manager application, the Manage button is disabled for the volume.

How can I add the new disk to the existing volume?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is not possible. I had to take backup of the data to a external USB drive, and then recreate the volume using both the harddisks. And then copy back the data into the new volume. 
Now its working fine.

Comment: I know this comment is late but I must ask. if you remove an existing SHR (no data protection) say Disk 1 - will the NAS still boot? I am under the impression that the DSM is installed in Disk 1, in my case i installed an 80GB as Disk 1 and setup DSM there, now, i added another 3TB drive... i want to upgrade the 80GB one into an 8TB or 10TB one, problem is, will it boot? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know you found a solution, but in case others read this, they should know that it ought to be possible to expand the existing volume (or disk group) - see this Synology tutorial for the details:
https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/storage_pool_expand_add_disk

In particular beware that the new disk you add to the volume has be at least the same size as the existing disk in your volume - otherwise you will not be allowed to expand your existing volume. 
From the Synology link:

- For SHR: The capacity of the hard drive you wish to add must be equal
  to or larger than **the largest hard drive** in the volume or disk group.
- For RAID 5 and RAID 6: The capacity of the hard drive you wish to add must be equal to or larger than **the smallest hard drive** in the volume or disk group.

Comment: I can confirm that the steps above link worked for me.  I just added a second drive to a DS213j (two bays). Had to shut it down while installing the drive (it's not hot-swap), and then go into Storage Manager to add the new disk to the Volume.  It took about six hours (overnight) to sync the new drive, but it was still accessible while that was happening.  My RAID type is SHR, and it now shows "data protection of 1-disk fault tolerance".

Comment: With the link broken, this answer does not provide much information anymore, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the link to a working version (as in working in August 2017 :-))

Comment: Link still (or again) points to the home page of Knowledge Database.

Comment: Hmm - Synology should really support deep links to the documentation  - but again I have updated the link - this time the link is at least known to be working December 20, 2018 :)

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue:

- Synology DS213 with a 3 TB hard drive
- I was adding another harddrive of at least 3 TB
- Raid of type **SHR** (Hybrid)

It is now very easy to add the drive (I have DSM 6.0.2 for what it matters)

1. Go to `Storage Manager` > `Volume`
2. Click on `Manage`
3. Select `Expand size` (I know, this is very misleading)
4. Select the new hard drive
5. Wait until the operation finishes: you can now see "with data protection of 1 disk fault-tolerance)

**Note**: you need to have at least the same size on the new drive and it's better to have similar model.

Cheers

Comment: Question: what is the new size on the volume? § TB + 3 TB = 6 TB ? Or less? Synology documentation: "For an SHR volume containing one drive, storage capacity will only be expanded when two or more drives are added."

https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/storage_pool_expand_add_disk

Comment: @Ivan a single drive of 4TB. And later on ,replaced by a single drive of 6TB. So no size increase

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for. At least in my case (DSM 6.1-15047 Update 2, Synology DS216+) I was able to add the new disk using the "Manage" function (Storage Manager -> Volume).

The Volume was already SHR, the second disk had the same size as the first.

Comment: What DSM version are you running? This question and it's solution are 4 years old. If you can be a bit more elaborate about what version you're running and what you did it could be a good answer.

Comment: I know, it's an old question. I decided to answer because i kept getting a link to it when searching for an guide, howto add another disk. My DS216+ is currently running DSM 6.1-15047 Update 2.

Comment: That would be one of the most recent versions. Your initial answer made it sound like you were running an older version. In addition the accepted answer doesn't really require any specific version and should work for your case as well. I did edit your answer to reflect the version you're using to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have Synology DS414, the 4-bay NAS with two 1TB disks installed and configured as one volume via SHR (Synology Hybrid RAID). Today I received two more 8TB drives. Here is what I did.

1. First of all DS414 supports hot-swapping, meaning I can add drives without turning off the NAS.
2. Having said that I installed one 8TB drive.
3. Waited, nothing changed. I can't see the drive in Storage Manager, and the "Manage" button is disabled. Very scared.
4. Decided to restart NAS.
5. After reboot => go to Storage Manager.
6. Now I see the "Manage" button is enabled.
7. Click on it and I see the "Choose an action" popup.
8. I choose "Expand the volume by adding hard disks". This is what I want, though there are other options.
9. In the next step it asks to "Choose disks". I choose the new drive which shows 7.28TB for its disk size.
10. Click "Next".
11. Click "Apply".
12. Now NAS starts expanding the volume by adding the new disk. But this process takes very long time, at least for my 8TB. It's been 24 minutes, and the process is only at 1.77% checking parity consistency.

I followed this help article from Synology https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/volume_diskgroup_expand_add_disk.